# French Pyrenees: Travel from Montréjeau—Gourdan-Polignan to Bagneres de Luchon

Tags: public-transport, france, pyrenees

I am looking into transport options between:

Montréjeau—Gourdan-Polignan to Bagneres de Luchon on Friday 27 July 2018.

So far, I am aware of the bus that leaves at 09h43. This seems to be the only public transport option for the day.

Is anyone aware of an alternate transport option?
- Public transport?
- Private taxi company?

Many thanks,
Jono

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Luchon),  "Due to the poor state of the Montréjeau–Luchon railway, operation of the line was suspended starting November 18, 2014, by SNCF and RFF; only TER coaches now offer the Montréjeau–Luchon trip.  As a consequence, the gare de Luchon is no longer operating."

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the [Luchon chamber of commerce page](http://www.luchon.com/accueil/luchonpratique/commentvenir.aspx) does not list any options beyond saying "Currently the Montréjeau–Luchon leg (37 km) is done by bus."

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for the same for next month.  Think the 9:43 is the once-per-day rail replacement bus, for possible 3 other times try
[Ligne 94](https://transports.haute-garonne.fr/index.php?n=94)